# How would I emphasize a definite noun? (Greek)

Tags: greek, articles, reflexive-pronoun

Suppose I want to be particularly emphatic about a noun: "the Fates themselves must have turned against me!" In Latin, I'd use some form of *ipse*; in Greek, my first instinct is *αὐτός*.

But I've also heard that *αὐτός* means "same" instead of being an intensifier when there's a definite article involved. That's not my goal here.

So if I also need to have a definite article (e.g. because the noun always takes one, like *αἱ Μοῖραι* "the Fates"), how would I make the noun more emphatic?

Comment: Also possible is *'gar'* (gamma alpha rho postpositive) and *'me:n'* (mu eta nu) postpositive particles to emphasise the noun.

Comment: @Hugh Good point! How do those differ from *autós*? That would make a good answer in and of itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the position of αὐτός.

- When it's in *attributive position*, it means 'same': ὁ αὐτὸς δοῦλος (also, more rarely, δοῦλος ὁ αὐτός or ὁ δοῦλος ὁ αὐτός), 'the same slave.'

  Example: Antiphon 5.50 ('On the murder of Herodes'):

  > ποτέρῳ οὖν εἰκός ἐστι πιστεῦσαι, τῷ διὰ τέλους **τὸν αὐτὸν ἀεὶ λόγον** λέγοντι, ἢ τῷ τοτὲ μὲν φάσκοντι τοτὲ δ᾽ οὔ;
  >
  > Which, then, have we more reason to believe: the witness who firmly adhered to **the same statement throughout**, or the witness who affirmed a thing at one moment, and denied it at the next?

  (Translation from [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0020%3Aspeech%3D5%3Asection%3D50))
- When it's in *predicate position*, it's an intensifier: ὁ δοῦλος αὐτός or αὐτὸς ὁ δοῦλος, 'the slave himself.'

  It's also an intensifier if it stands alone in the nominative case. In such cases, it's emphasizing the subject pronoun that's understood from the verb ending: αὐτὸς ἔπεσον, 'I myself fell.'

  Example: Thucydides 1.114.3:

  > καὶ Ἀθηναῖοι πάλιν ἐς Εὔβοιαν διαβάντες Περικλέους στρατηγοῦντος κατεστρέψαντο πᾶσαν, καὶ τὴν μὲν ἄλλην ὁμολογίᾳ κατεστήσαντο, Ἑστιαιᾶς δὲ ἐξοικίσαντες **αὐτοὶ τὴν γῆν ἔσχον**.
  >
  > The Athenians then crossed over again to Euboea under the command of Pericles, and subdued the whole of the island: all but Histiaea was settled by convention; the Histiaeans they expelled from their homes, and **occupied their territory themselves**.

  (Translation from [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0200%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D114))
- And, of course, when it stands alone in cases other than the nominative, it's generally just the third person pronoun, 'he'/'she'/'it.' (Though, as Smyth, *Greek grammar* §1208 points out, it can sometimes emphasize a noun, or a pronoun, that must be supplied from context; and certainly, in both the examples that Smyth provides [Thucydides 4.78.4 and Demosthenes 2.2], the noun/pronoun that must be supplied is quite obvious.)

Comment: For OP, *autos* and *ipse* are almost the same word, the latter being an emphatic enclitic fused to the third-person pronoun: *is-pse.* earlier latin even has forms like *ea-pse* and *eam-pse.*

Comment: @Anonym: Nice point. And to take it further, idem is likewise formed from is + dem. So, whereas Greek can use αὐτός as 3rd person pronoun, emphatic '-self'/'-selves,' and 'same,' thanks especially to its definite article, Latin has to differentiate the 3 uses through enclitics/suffixes.